# how to make google crypto.js cypher output a string?

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I want to have an offline webpage containing javascript that will encrypt a string with a key and result in another string. Then I want to do the reverse.

This is a simple tool that I would run offline so I would prefer to keep the conversation away from client side encryption.

For now i've chosen google crypto.js as my cypher and for this example I'm using Rabbit

here is my jdfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Pz3ab/

which uses jquery and the following external resource

http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Rabbit

Where am I going wrong?

```
<div>key<br><input class="key" type="text"></div>
<div>readout<br><input class="readout" type="text"></div>
<div>
    <div class="button encrypt">encrypt</div>
    <div class="button decrypt">decrypt</div>
</div>
<div class="error"><div>

var key,readout;
$('.encrypt').on('click', function(){
    if (init()) {
        console.log('-- encrypt clicked --');
        console.log('key = ', key);
        console.log('readout = ', readout);
        var answer = CryptoJS.Rabbit.encrypt(readout, key);
        answer = answer.toString();
        console.log('answer = ',answer);
        $('.readout').val(answer);
    }
});
$('.decrypt').on('click', function(){
    if (init()) {
        console.log('-- decrypt clicked --');
        console.log('key = ', key);
        console.log('readout = ', readout);
        var answer=CryptoJS.Rabbit.decrypt(readout, key);
        answer = answer.toString();
        console.log('answer = ',answer);
        $('.readout').val(answer);
    }
});
function init(){
    key = '' + $('.key').val();
    readout = '' + $('.readout').val();
    console.log('-- init, error check, get key and readout --');
    console.log('key = ', key);
    console.log('readout = ', readout);
    $('.error').empty();
    var success = true;
    if (key=="") {$('.error').append('key is empty<br>');success=false;}
    if (readout=="") {$('.error').append('readout is empty<br>');success=false;}
    return success;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Please see this page: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: @MattBall  try using the jsfiddle link, you should be able to put in a key and a message in the readout. pressing encrypt would turn the readout to the encrypted string, pressing decrypt would turn it back. At the moment it doesn't work. Something to do with the toString() but I don;t want an object. I've tried AES as well as Rabbit

Comment: @ntoskrnl you totally ignored that I wrote I would be using this offline?  I also specifially requested that this not get into a discussion about client side ecryption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: `answer.toString( CryptoJS.enc.Utf8 );`

Long answer: The decrypted otuput you're seeing is the original readout string encoded as hex. The reason it's encoded as hex is because the cipher algorithms have no way to know the original character encoding. Was it Latin1? Utf8? Utf16? Etc. By passing the Utf8 encoder to the toString method, we can tell it to use that character encoding.

Comment: Hi Jeff, in order to try that I included enc-utf16-min.js and received and error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lib' of undefined

Comment: okay so I've included core-min and it no longer crashes but the toString fix you suggested results in nothing.  Here is a the new jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PrimeLens/xVU3b/1/

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realized that you used the variable name "answer" twice. You want to use `answer.toString( CryptoJS.enc.Utf8 )` only during the decryption step. Also, as long as you load utf16 after rabbit.js, then it should work fine. You shouldn't need to load core.

Comment: Oh, its difficult not to got frustrated. `answer.toString( CryptoJS.enc.Utf8 )` does not specify a cypher key which is why I took you to mean that it goes alongside what I wrote, not replacing it. The problem with `answer=CryptoJS.Rabbit.decrypt(readout, key)` is that it returns an object which makes it useless if you want to say copy and paste the resulting encryption into an email.

Comment: That's what toString() is for.

Comment: the last jsfiddle clarified everything. Sincere thanks. Frustrations gone, have all my upvotes